# Use enum constructor directly in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

Is it possible to use the enum constructor directly?

```dart
void main() {
  print(Test(1));
}

enum Test {
  test1(1),
  test2(2);
  
  final int id;

  const Test(this.id);
}
```

This will give the following error:

> generative enum constructors can only be used as targets of redirection

I know that it can be solved like this:

```dart
enum Test {
  test1(1),
  test2(2);

  final int id;

  const Test(this.id);
  
  factory Test.fromId(int id) {
    return values.firstWhere((e) => e.id == id);
  }
}
```

But it feels like there must be a way to avoid this boiler plate factory?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't think there is an easier way than that factory. My personal opinion is also that it really isn't that much of boiler plate, but that's subjective.

One reason I can think of why there isn't an easier method, is because the `id` in your case is not unique, this is perfectly valid:

```
enum Test {
  test1(1),
  secondtest1(1),
  test2(2);

  final int id;

  const Test(this.id);
  
  factory Test.fromId(int id) {
    return values.firstWhere((e) => e.id == id);
  }
}
```

Now you will never be able to get the `secondtest1` using the `fromId`

Comment: Right, I forgot that they aren't unique. Then it makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Found this reference too that might fit in the answer:
https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#invalid_reference_to_generative_enum_constructor